# Opencv cv:Mat::at allows to modify only part of the image

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm playing around with opencv 3.2 (new to this library), and noticed some weird behavour of the `cv::Mat::at` method.

1st when typing `myMat.at` help notes about method signature don't show up in QTcreator but do show up for the rest of the methods

2nd when iterating over pixels of the image it modifies only some part of the image (I'll better show a screenshot and the code)

[image]

the code

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    cv::Mat orignalImg = cv::imread("/path/to/image/pic3.jpg", cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);
    cv::Mat modifiedImg = cv::imread("/path/to/image/pic3.jpg", cv::IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);

    for (int r = 0; r < modifiedImg.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < modifiedImg.cols; ++c)
        {
            modifiedImg.at<uint8_t>(r, c) = modifiedImg.at<uint8_t>(r, c) * 0.2f;
        }
    }

    cv::imshow("original", orignalImg);
    cv::imshow("modified", modifiedImg);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return a.exec();
}
```

As you can see the image on the right side isn't completely processed, but only part of it.

Why is this happening ?
According to the code it should process whole image.

what Am I missing there?

Comment: You're using `cv::Mat::at` incorrectly. You have colour (i.e. 3-channel images), yet you do `at<uint8_t>` instead of `at<Vec3b>`...

Comment: @DanMašek why is that incorrect ?? 3 channel means rgb color model which needs unsigned char (0, 255) for each channel isnt it ?

Comment: Sure, but you're not specifying a channel, only the row and column when accessing those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're accessing the `Mat` with `at<uint8_t>` (btw, you should've used `at<uchar>` instead), meaning that the image is of type `CV_8UC1`, i.e. a matrix of 1 channel (`C1`) with underlying type 8 bit unsigned (`8U`).

However, your is a color image, which means that it has 3 channels (`C3`) with type 8 bit unsigned (`8U`), which means 8 bit for representing each of the color B,G,R (`0:255`). This means that the image is of type `CV_8UC3`, and you should access it with `at<cv::Vec3b>`.

So your code becomes:

```
 modifiedImg.at<Vec3b>(r, c) = modifiedImg.at<Vec3b>(r, c) * 0.2f;
```

You can also avoid to scan the image, and use directly:

```
modifiedImg = modifiedImg * 0.2f;
```

---

You can also use `imread` with `cv::IMREAD_COLOR` (the default) to be sure to load the image with 3 channels.

Comment: yeah I tried before using vec3b and it worked as expected, but with uchar it still outputs the same bug

Comment: It's not a bug, you're just doing it wrong. The correct way to work with a CV_8UC3 matrix is with Vec3b.

Comment: but on the windows machine that works as expected, I mean when using uint8_t it fills whole image

Comment: Because you're probably loading a grayscale (1 channel) image. You can check the number of channels with your_image.channels()

Comment: oh sorry yeah it was loading as grayscale :)